# Achieve the below syntax(for Factory design patters) in any compiled language? preferably Kotlin, C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, factory-pattern, kotlin-native

I want to know if the below syntax is available for a compiled langue?
Please do not provide java as it requires the JVM. The design is equivalent to a factory design pattern as we initialize a class once some test passes in normal situations we use lots of if-else statements i.e When we have a range of classes we i.e 10 classes the code becomes clunky
I am trying to create a language transpiled or compiled not decided on that yet and would looking into features capabilities of the already compiled languages currently working with kotlin-native and llvm (not yet sorted llvm integration) it's on startup and that is what I want to consider using.

```js
class A{
   
}

class B extends A{
  
}



class C extends A{
   
}

class D extends A{
   
}

class E extends A{
   
}

class F extends A{
   
}

class G extends A{
   
}

class H extends A{
   
}

class I extends A{
   
}

class J extends A{
   
}

class K extends A{
   
}
function getClass(test){
    if(test == 1){
      return new B()
    }else if (test == 2){
      return new C()
    }else if (test == 3){
      return new D()
    }else if (test == 4){
      return new E()
    }else if (test == 5){
      return new F()
    }else if (test == 6){
      return new G()
    }else if (test == 7){
      return new H()
    }else if (test == 8){
      return new I()
    }else if (test == 9){
      return new J()
    }else if (test == 10){
      return new K()
    }
}

let klass = getClass(10)

console.log(`Found class ${klass.constructor.name}`)
```

```js
class A {    
    static test(test) {
        return test === this.index;
    }
}


class B extends A{}

B.index = 1

class C extends A{}

C.index = 2

class D extends A{}

D.index = 3

class E extends A{}

E.index = 4

class F extends A{}

F.index = 5

class G extends A{}

G.index = 6

class H extends A{}

H.index = 7

class I extends A{}

I.index = 8

class J extends A{}

J.index = 9

class K extends A{}

K.index = 10

let klasses = [B, C,D,E,F,G,H,I,G,K];

let klass = new A();

let test = 7;

for (let i = 0; i < klasses.length; i++) {
    try {
      if(klasses[i].test(test)){
          klass =  new klasses[i]()
      }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}


console.log(`Found class ${klass.constructor.name}`);
```

Comment: You *do* know that Kotlin is a JVM-based language?

Comment: As for parsing a syntax, *any* syntax, you could use just about any Turing-complete language.

Comment: @Some-programmer-dude you do know there is kotlin native?? I know kotlin has a jvm but it also has cinterop

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to implement the pattern in some other language? Then *what* language? And why do you have the `compiler-construction` tag? Are you trying to create a compiler yourself? Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I have removed the compiler tag then.

Comment: Is the point here the `new klasses[i]()`? bit?  Adding a covariant virtual `clone()` to `A` and making `klasses` a factory array would do it for you in that case, though specializing for factory and product types would probably wind up cleaner in real code.

Comment: Can u provide a simple demonstration for this? As I would assume clone function would do more of copy a previous instance, of which I would have to reset the required state properties to the current clone requirements or default instantiation values?

Comment: Yes the problem is the new klasses[i]() bit where I do not want to create a separate class on every time i want to use this design pattern i.e class A, class AFactory. This somewhat moves form simple code to a form of data entry as you would be repetitive on an end goal that is static.

Comment: Then you want the covariant-return `clone()` method, since you're already supplying a reference object per class (for its `index` member) you might as well get full value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify your question? Your previous question [How can I achieve the below syntax in any compiled language? preferably Kotlin, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435012/how-can-i-achieve-the-below-syntax-in-any-compiled-language-preferably-kotlin) actually seemed clearer to me. Could you maybe give us information on what high-level goal you are trying to achieve?

Are you trying to design a new language? Are you trying to pick a language to implement your new language's parser in?

Going by your code, you are trying to design a language where classes are kept as a list, in order of declaration, and then you want to be able to instantiate all those classes by iterating the list somehow, and the classes are supposed to be able to know their own index in the list for other uses?

Is that what you're trying to do?

In most languages, classes can't be kept in arrays. They aren't actual objects. But some, like Smalltalk, Objective-C, Self or TADS, implicitly create an object for each class that contains additional data (C++ has an atrophied form of this called "runtime type-information", or RTTI).

If your implementation language doesn't do that, you'll have to do that yourself. Create objects that contain a function that creates an object of the right subclass (and maybe contains some other information like the class name or index in the list so you can find it again), and add that "maker" object to a global list. Then just use this global list of factory objects to create your instances.

You're not saying how you are creating your language though. Are you writing a tool that reads a text file in your language and turns it into a source file in an existing language? Then that tool would just have to create the source code for a few additional classes (like, for `class B`, it would also create a `class B_Maker` that is a subclass of `class A_Maker`, but creates a new object of type `B`, and then it would create some `init()` function containing code to crete a new object of each maker and add them to the global list).

If you're modifying LLVM or some other existing compiler chain, or trying to do this from scratch, the basic approach would be the same (unless there is already an existing object for each class that you can just extend), but you wouldn't be generating source code, but some other data structures that result in the equivalent code being compiled in the end.

Give us more context, and we might be able to help.

Comment: As you can see that question was put on hold for some reason and had to rethink the question. So here I ask if there is any language which is capable for that structure and yes I have considered creating classes with their static holder i.e class A having its static as AStatic where that is what would be instantiated inside the array let klasses = [new BStatic()] etc. Yes I am trying to implement my own language and I also want to use that structure in my code and also want to translate to whatever language that will support the structure if not I would consider using class BStatic  structure.

Comment: It's good that you rethought the question, but it would have been helpful to include *more* information instead of even less. Give us more detail on *how* you are going about in creating your own language, and include it in your original question. From this comment, I am taking it you are building a transpiler? Something that takes a source file in your language and turns it into a Java *source file*, not a compiler that outputs native code? Add details like that to your question. We can't read your mind, so we can't answer  your question in a sensible way.

Comment: I.e. what your question should include: 1. what are you trying to do? (e.g. "I am trying to build a simpler way of registering my control classes so I can create the right one when loading from a file" or something) 2. How are you trying to do it? (e.g. "I'm building my own domain-specific language that will be translated into Java source code") 3. What are your constraints? (e.g. "I'm running on a Raspberry Pi" or "the people using this system will be non-programmers with finance and HTML knowledge") ... give us something to work with.

Comment: Just wanted to know if the feature is implemented in any language as it would be a great syntax for my personal factory-design pattern syntax than having to create whole factory class with untidy if statements and also for the language design and well that makes a broad scope and had to break it to one section i.e if the syntax is available for any other language than javascript. as I am using kotlin-native and i can integrate it together if it is in either c++ or kotlin-native.